# Ruby 1.9 - no such file to load 'win32/open3'

Tags: ruby

I'm running ruby 1.9.2 on Windows and am trying to port code that worked in Ruby 1.8.  The code uses Open4.popen4 which previously worked fine.  With 1.9.2 I have done the following:

1. Installed POpen4 via `gem install POpen4`
2. Required POpen4 via `require 'popen4'`
3. Attempted to use POpen4 like: 
   `Open4.popen4("cmd") {|io_in,io_out,io_er| ... }`

When I do, I get the error:
`no such file to load -- win32/open3`

If I try and install win32-open3 (`gem install win32-open3`) I get the error:

`win32-open3 requires Ruby version < 1.9.0`

Does anyone know how I get around this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Haven't used it, but this might work: https://github.com/matschaffer/win32-open3-19

Comment: Worked for me. Added to Gemfile

gem "win32-open3-19", :platforms => :mingw, :git => "https://github.com/matschaffer/win32-open3-19.git"

Comment: Adding just this `gem "win32-open3-19", :platforms => :mingw` to my `Gemfile` worked for me.

Comment: FWIW, the 1.9 way to get open4's behavior is in https://github.com/matschaffer/win32-open3-19/blob/master/lib/win32/open3.rb My gem is just a wrapper for situations where you don't have full control over the gem dependency chain.

Comment: I also had to add only 'gem "win32-open3-19", :platforms => :mingw' to my Gemfile (without the :git=>). Otherwise I got "fatal: Could not switch to 'github.com/matschaffer': No such file or directory..."  I assume you have to have "source 'http://gems.github.com'" in the Gemfile too in order for that to work without the ":git=>" part.

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
gem "win32-open3-19", :platforms => :mingw, :git => "github.com/matschaffer/win32-open3-19.git"
```

to my Gemfile didn't exactly work.

Here are the steps that solved this for me:

1. Add this to the Gemfile -> `gem 'win32-open3-19', :platforms => :mingw`
2. Run **bundle** to install win32-open3-19

That was it. For me the git location was unncessary and didn't work.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to add this answer. it was this one that did it for me. i didn't know enough ruby to know what the first answer met. well done thanks.