# Problems with jammit gem on windows x64

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, jammit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ruby 1.9 - no such file to load 'win32/open3'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930270/ruby-1-9-no-such-file-to-load-win32-open3)

I am having a problem with jammit gem. When I run "rake", I get a message telling me, there is a problem - part of message:

$ rake -t
(in c:/Ruby187/test)
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- win32/open3
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
:in require'
c:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239
:inrequire'

Some info about environment:
OS: Windows 7 64bit
Ruby 1.8.7
GEMS:
jammit (0.6.0)
closure-compiler (1.1.1)
yui-compressor (0.9.6)

If I remove jammit from Gemfile, command rake -t runs without problems.

Thank you for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'win32-open3'
```

and bundle

Comment: Obvious but invisible solution, for user with 1 week of experience in RoR. :) Thank you!!!

Comment: Note for newcomers: This however does not work on Ruby 2.0. Adding gem 'win32-open3-19' works, as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930270/ruby-1-9-no-such-file-to-load-win32-open3

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer didn't work for me because it complained that my Ruby version must be less than 1.9 (on Windows 7 64-bit).  However, this command worked and jammit started working after the gem was installed:

```
gem install win32-open3-19
```